# Server error 500 when adding .htaccess file in the root folder

Tags: .htaccess, localhost

I read a lot of server error 500 questions related to the famous .htaccess file...but I have still not found an answer to this error.

I have a folder which i used to test the .htaccess file.

=>`http://localhost/xampp/example/`

I copied the .htaccess in the example folder and I get server error 500

I checked in my error.log file and found this: `.htaccess RewriteEngine not allowed here`

But I changed all `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` in my httpd.conf file I also uncommented the line `LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so`

error log says: `ExpiresActive not allowed here`

what is actually happening??...how can I resolve this error??

This is what I have in my .htaccess file now...

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 days"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: What is in Apache error log? Can you show us the .htaccess file?

Comment: This is in the .htaccess file:

# This folder does not require access over HTTP
# (the following directive denies access by default)
Order allow,deny

where can i find the Apache error log?

Comment: The error log says: ExpiresActive not allowed here

Comment: Weird, `ExpiresActive` is OK when you have `AllowOverride Indexes` (which I think is automaticaly included in  `AllowOverride all`). Are you sure, that you have no other `AllowOverride`s?

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this error when I've tried to use features of .htaccess not allowed in the Apache `AllowOverride` configuration parameter. If you have access to your Apache configuration, try setting this to the level you need, or maybe `All` to allow full .htaccess capabilities.

Comment: Thanks so much for replying quickly...But i am new to this..please be patient with me...first i copied an .htaccess file in the folder..and when i try to access any page from "example" folder the 500 error is displayed..where should i be changing the Apache configuration?...I heard that you have to enable the rewrite engine...

Comment: The location of the configuration file(s) varies by system. Which operating system are you running? If Linux, which distribution? I'm assuming the web server is running on your personal computer?

Comment: Try checking the installation directory for a file called httpd.conf, sites.conf or something similar. Maybe you could run a search for a file containing the text "AllowOverride". Once you find it, change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All".

Comment: I found the file httpd.conf and i changed the "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All".. but i still get the 500 error...

i can't understand why when i remove evrything in the .htaccess file...i can access any page in the "example" folder correctly...So could the problem be with the .htaccess file??

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing the value?

Comment: yea multiple of time...
There's something in the error.log..i was looking everywhere..and found the error.log..it says:"RewriteEngine not allowed here","RewriteRule not allowed here"....Why are they not allowed?...

Comment: AllowOverride specifies what kind of commands can be used in the .htaccess files, but All should allow all of them. Check if there are more references to AllowOverride in the configuration files, it's possible you changed the wrong one.

Comment: If you don't know which one to change, the surest way is to change them all. I'm not familiar with XAMPP's directory structure so I can't offer more specific tips.

Comment: I think its desperate i double checked everything...and it still gives me the error 500...

Comment: Did you change all of them? Do you still get the same error in the log?

Comment: sadly...yes...i think i looked at all the questions in stackoverflow and in serverfault...i am just left perplexed...

Answer (score 2):

First, Go to your apache’s httpd.conf file
I my case its “C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf”

The lines beginning with # indicate that these are comments
Remove the comments for these below mentioned lines

```
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today. In my case, the problem was because I saved the `.htaccess` file with UTF-8 encoding, but I forgot to remove the BOM (byte order mark). When I saved as UTF-8 without BOM, the problem was solved !